# Iterable output type of Apache Beam GroupByKey.create() on FlinkRunner

Tags: apache-beam

The output of Apache-Beam GroupByKey.create() transformation is PCollection< KV< K,Iterable< V>>>.

When I run the code **using FlinkRunner (batch mode)**, I see that the Iterable< V> is an ArrayList.

Does it mean that the grouped elements per key has to be fit into Memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I guess so. `GroupByKey` translation uses `Combiner` to combine all values with the same key and `ArrayList` is used as internal container for that. So, it could be a potential NPE issue with hot keys.

See details of implementation: [one](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7120cebf936da58febc00f931bc0450d2b515418/runners/flink/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/flink/FlinkBatchTransformTranslators.java#L241) and [two](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7120cebf936da58febc00f931bc0450d2b515418/runners/flink/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/flink/FlinkBatchTransformTranslators.java#L330)